# Completely new to Active Admin, can someone clarify how it accesses app models?

Tags: activeadmin

I have just installed active admin, and I am unsure of how it accesses data from models I have created.

I've read the active admin documentation, but it's not very clear abut where code to customize/access information should be saved- dashboard.rb? active_admin.rb?

Do I need to add files/code to allow active admin to access other models in the app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to register you're model with **Activeadmin**

`rails generate active_admin:resource MODEL_NAME`

Then it creates a file under `/app/admin` with you're model name. There you can customize/access required information.

Comment: Once I've generated it and permitted the params from the model, do I need to do anything else? I'm simply trying to access the data from the model via an activeadmin dashboard, but the documentation isn't super clear about how I might go about that.

Comment: i think everything is clearly explained here [link](https://activeadmin.info/documentation.html). How to customise and all.If it doesn't helps, please mention what sort of data you're trying to access from model?